# Xamarin.Forms DynamicResource doesn't seem to be working

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I can't seem to get a `DynamicResource` working correctly.

Here's the XAML in App.xml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Thickness x:Key ="DefaultInsets"
                   Bottom="4"
                   Top   ="4"
                   Left  ="8"
                   Right ="8" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And here's what I'm trying to do inside another file's `ContentView`:

```
<StackLayout 
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
    HeightRequest="225" 
    Margin="{DynamicResource DefaultInsets}" >
        <Entry
            x:Name="nameControl"
            Placeholder="Full Name"
            Margin="{DynamicResource DefaultInsets}"
            />
        <Entry
            x:Name="passwordControl"
            IsPassword="True"
            Placeholder="Password"
            Margin="{DynamicResource DefaultInsets}" />
</StackLayout>
```

It seems like this should make consistent insets for the `StackLayout` from the `ContentView`, and for the `Entry` fields from the `StackLayout`. But I don't see any of that.

What have I done wrong?

**Update** : I have also tried this with `StaticResource`, and still no luck.

Comment: DefaultInsets is a StaticResource as it's defined here. The difference is that a StaticResource does a single lookup for the value, where a DynamicResource keeps an eye on the ResourceDictionary entry and watches for changes to the value, and applies them. If you aren't changing the value in App's RD, you should be using a StaticResource. Is the ContentView defined in the same assembly as App.xaml?

Comment: @MaxHampton Yes, they're in the same assembly, if I understand you correctly. So I should be accessing it as a StaticResource, I get you. Thing is though, I've tried that too, before, and it still doesn't work. Do you think I should edit the OP to remove reference to DynamicResources, as it might confuse the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers may be valid for some people, but in the end here's what I was doing wrong:

`InitializeComponent()` was never getting called inside `App.xaml.cs.`

I had an if-then statement that was always hitting a `return` before ever getting to `InitializeComponent().`

When that doesn't get called, `App.xaml` is inaccessible to the rest of the app, and nothing defined there is available as a `DynamicResource`.

So I moved `InitializeComponent()` to happen before the if-then statement, and now it all works like gangbusters.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

I use following type with `ResourceDictionary`. For distinguish, I set the top_margin to 40, here is my screenshot.

[image]

Here is my `ResourceDictionary`.

```
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="OuterPadding" x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="Android">8 ,40,8,4</On>
            <On Platform="iOS">20</On>
            <On Platform="WinPhone">24</On>
        </OnPlatform>
        <!--  left, top, right, and bottom-->
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

Here is my layout.

```
    <StackLayout 
     VerticalOptions="Center" 
     HeightRequest="225" 
     Margin="{DynamicResource OuterMargin}" >
        <Entry
        x:Name="nameControl"
        Placeholder="Full Name"
        Margin="{DynamicResource OuterMargin}"
        />
        <Entry
        x:Name="passwordControl"
        IsPassword="True"
        Placeholder="Password"
        Margin="{DynamicResource OuterMargin}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

**Update**

I found you layout issue is related to the `VerticalOptions="Center"` in the `StackLayout`(If you set the `VerticalOptions="Center"`, then set the margin value is not work).

If I delete it and use `StaticResource`.

Here is running screenshot(For testing, I change the value of margin top to 20)

[image]

Comment: The only difference seems to be that you are using `OnPlatform`. Does your code work without that?

Comment: I will check that out, in the meantime you might want to change `OuterPadding` in your `ResourceDictionary` example to `OuterMargin`, so it matches your updated `StackLayout` example.